# How upload a image using Firebase storage on server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create an upload function using Firebase storage on the server side.

Upload function on the server side:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cors = require("cors");
const uuid = require("uuid");
const { getDownloadURL, uploadBytes, ref } = require("firebase/storage");

admin.initializeApp();

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

const corsMiddleware = cors();

exports.upload = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsMiddleware(req, res, async () => {
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            return res.status(405).end();
        }

        try {
            const image = req.file;

            console.log(`Here: ${image}`);

            const storageRef = ref(
                bucket,
                `uploaded-images/${image}_${uuid.v4()}`
            );

            const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, image);

            uploadTask
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    console.log("File successfully uploaded.");
                    return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
                })
                .then((downloadURL) => {
                    return res.send({
                        success: true,
                        url: downloadURL,
                    });
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
            return res
                .status(500)
                .json({ success: false, error: "Internal Server Error" });
        }
    });
});
```

I also created a handleUpload function on the client side just to call the upload function above:

```
const handleUpload = async (image: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const fileInput = image.target;
        if (!fileInput || !fileInput.files || fileInput.files.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
    
        const selectedFile = fileInput.files[0];
        if (!selectedFile) {
            return;
        }

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', selectedFile);

        try {
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                body: formData,
            };
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/professional-vision-262b8/us-central1/upload', options);
            const data = await response.json();

            if (data.success) {
                console.log('Upload successful!');
                console.log('Image URL:', data.url);
                setSelectedImage(selectedFile);
                setModalOpen(true);
            } else {
                console.error('Error uploading image:', data.error);
            }
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to upload, I get this error:

`Beginning execution of "us-central1-upload"`

`>  req.file: undefined`

`>  Error uploading image: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')`

I placed the 'file' key as the image that was supposed to be uploaded on the client side on this part:

```
formData.append('file', selectedFile);
```

But even with that, I continuously get req.file = undefined.

I tried to use:

`const image = req.body.file`

`const image = req.files.file`

`const image = req.files['file']`

But I had no success. Where I'm going wrong?

Edit:

I applied multer to handle with the upload, as it is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require("multer");
const uuid = require("uuid");
const { getDownloadURL, uploadBytes, ref } = require("firebase/storage");

admin.initializeApp();

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const corsMiddleware = cors();

exports.upload = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsMiddleware(req, res, async () => {
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            return res.status(405).end();
        }

        try {
            upload.single("file")(req, res, async function (err) {
                if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                    console.error("Multer error:", err);
                    return res
                        .status(500)
                        .json({ success: false, error: "Multer error" });
                } else if (err) {
                    console.error("Error uploading file:", err);
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        success: false,
                        error: "Internal Server Error",
                    });
                }

                const image = req.file;

                const storageRef = ref(
                    bucket,
                    `uploaded-images/image_${uuid.v4()}`
                );

                const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, image.buffer);

                uploadTask
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        console.log("File successfully uploaded.");
                        return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
                    })
                    .then((downloadURL) => {
                        return res.send({
                            success: true,
                            url: downloadURL,
                        });
                    });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
            return res
                .status(500)
                .json({ success: false, error: "Internal Server Error" });
        }
    });
});
```

But I'm getting this error now:

```
"Error uploading file: Error: Unexpected end of format Multipart._final"
```

I tried to pass on the options to the client:

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
};
```

And tried to convert the formData to blob before passing on the response to the client, however still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
>  req.file: undefined
```

In your server-side code, you are trying to access it as req.file, which is not the standard way to handle file uploads in Express.js. To handle file uploads in Express.js, you typically use a middleware like multer. Here's how you can modify your server-side code to handle file uploads using multer:

Install multer as a dependency in your Firebase Functions project:
bash

```
npm install multer
```

After is update your server-side code to use multer:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storageConfig = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storageConfig });
```

This code uses multer to handle file uploads and stores the uploaded file in Google Cloud Storage.

With this setup, you should be able to send files from the client side, and the server will handle the file upload correctly.

Comment: I applied multer to handle the upload, but I got a new error. I edited my answer with the error. Do have any idea what could be?